# Sort and Merge Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I have to merge two arrays and sort by created value based on comparison. I don't want to use any inbuilt js functions like sort. I tried using while loop but couldn't figure out exact solution. Here is my sample code:

```
function merge(a, b, n, m)  
{  
    res = []; 
    i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;  
    while(i < n && j < m) {
        if(a[i]['created'] < b[j]['created']) {
            res.push(a[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            res.push(b[j]);
            j++;
        }        
    }

    while(i < n) {
        res.push(a[i]);
        i++;
    }

    while(j < m) {
        res.push(b[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return res;  
}  

a = [{'title':'title1', 'created':'18'},{'title':'title2', 'created':'16'},{'title':'title3', 'created':'20'}];  
b = [{'title':'title4','created':'17'},{'title':'title5','created':'19'}];  
n = a.length;  
m = b.length;  

var endResult = merge(a, b, n, m);  
console.log(endResult);
```

My expected Output should be as follows:

```
[{'title':'title2', 'created':'16'},{'title':'title4','created':'17'},{'title':'title1', 'created':'18'},{'title':'title5','created':'19'},{'title':'title3', 'created':'20'}];
```

Please let me know what i missed out here.

**Note: I don't want to use in-built Javascript function like sort(). I have to sort values based on specific business logic, which i shall implement after figuring out basic sort.**

Comment: Is this some kind of interview "stump you with algs" question? Why wouldn't you use the functions any professional would use to do this?

Comment: @TimConsolazio My end result is not just a sorted array. I have to implement many other conditions for sorting. Just i am stuck up with basic sorting part.

Comment: The first issue I can note is that you are only comparing elements of array `a` with elements of array `b`. You need to compare elements that belong to the same array too.

Comment: @GaneshBabu Sounds like the introduction to an XY Problem.

Comment: Don't use `in-built functions` is a rather strange ask. What exactly are the restrictions? Can you use `for` loops and other array methods? Or... what?

Comment: @zfrisch I meant functions like sort, asort ... as in-built functions. for, while are no restrictions.

Comment: @TylerRoper I have to sort values based on specific business logic, which i shall implement after figuring out basic sort.

Comment: I understand that, I just think that you should ask the question from the ground-up. Explain what you're trying to achieve - your end goal, rather than asking about your specific solution to it. It's the very definition of an XY Problem. Avoiding built-in JavaScript functions is the indication of a bigger issue. The `sort()` function is completely customizeable...

Comment: Writing a `sort` routine is straightforward.  There are plenty of examples of BubbleSorts, QuickSorts, TimSorts, MergeSorts, and others online.  While you could easily write your own version of one of these, it would very likely offer nothing over writing your code with a custom comparator supplied to the built-in `sort`.  You can even reuse that comparator in a `merge` step.  A custom `sort` only makes sense if you're doing it as a learning exercise.

Comment: You are aware that you can write sort functions for use in sort() to handle almost any custom business case?

Comment: Many of these comments make the same point. What is wrong with the available functional ways of doing sorts? Is there an explicit restriction not to use them to achieve your result? If so, the problem isn't a hard one to solve, it's just seems overly contrived.

Answer (score 2):

A simple O(n^2) solution would be to loop through all elements looking for the lowest value, then looping through them all again looking for the second lowest value, etc.

```js
function mergeSort(a, b) {
    var array = a.concat(b);
    var length = array.length;
    var results = [];
    while(results.length < length) {
 var currentLowest = 0;
 for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
     if(array[i].created < array[currentLowest].created) {
  currentLowest = i;
     }
 }
 results.push(array[currentLowest]);
 array.splice(currentLowest,1);
    }
    return results;
}

a = [{'title':'title1', 'created':'18'},{'title':'title2', 'created':'16'},{'title':'title3', 'created':'20'}];  
b = [{'title':'title4','created':'17'},{'title':'title5','created':'19'}];

var endResult = mergeSort(a,b);
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(endResult);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested loop and sort the array after concat.

```js
function sort(array) {
    var sorted = [],
        i = array.length,
        j;

    while (i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++) {
            if (array[i].created < sorted[j].created) {
                break;
            }
        }
        sorted.splice(j, 0, array[i]);
    }
    return sorted;
}

var a = [{ title: 'title1', created: '18' }, { title: 'title2', created: '16' }, { title: 'title3', created: '20' }],
    b = [{ title: 'title4', created: '17' }, { title: 'title5', created: '19'}],
    result = sort(a.concat(b));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well, although I can't speak to its speed.

```
  const arr1 = [111,2,300,50,6,71,9];
  const arr2 = [122,8,40,29,611,74,1];
  // Combines the two arrays into one
  const unsorted = arr1.concat(arr2);
  const sorted = [];

  for(i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++){
    // Adds all elements from the unsorted array to the destination (sorted) array
    insert(unsorted[i], sorted);
  }
  console.log(sorted);

  function insert(item, arr){
    // Adds the first item automatically
    if(arr.length == 0){
      arr.push(item); 
      return; 
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(i + 1 == arr.length){
        // Adds the item at the end of the array because it's so big 
        arr.push(item);
        break;
      }

      else if(item < arr[i]){
        // Adds the item at the appropriate position in the sorted array
        arr.splice(i, 0, item);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do with the built-in `sort` and `concat` functions.

Custom logic can be supplied to the comparator function.  It's hard to imagine any required sorting that can't be done this way.

```js
// `comparator` contains your custom business logic.  Return a negative number if `a`
// is smaller than `b`, a positive one if it's larger, and 0 if they're equal.

const mergeAndSort = (comparator) => (a, b) => a.concat(b).sort(comparator)

const myComparator = (a, b) => {
  return Number(a.created) - Number(b.created)  // or just `a.created - `b.created`
}

const a = [{ title: 'title1', created: '18' }, { title: 'title2', created: '16' }, { title: 'title3', created: '20' }],
      b = [{ title: 'title4', created: '17' }, { title: 'title5', created: '19'}]

console.log(mergeAndSort(myComparator)(a, b))
```

Is this an attempt to learn how to write a sort algorithm?  If not, then I would go with an approach like this.